# Why can't I shrink my logfile below to the requested value?

Tags: sql-server, shrink, log, dbcc

Experimenting VLFs behaviors with my test lab. Firsty, I have created two databases (BASE2 & BASE3) with different log files size (1024 & 2048 MO) :

[image]

Secondly, I'am running the following queries to determine log space usage and the active portion of the VLF :

```
USE BASE2
dbcc loginfo
GO
USE BASE3
dbcc loginfo
GO
```

[image]

```
DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)
```

[image]

So in my opinion there is plenty of space that I can reclaim. Now starting this query to shrink all databases log files :

```
DECLARE
@db nvarchar(255),
@fileName nvarchar(255),
@cmd nvarchar(255)

BEGIN

DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT table2.name AS BASE, table1.name AS FICHIER_JOURNAL_BASE

    --table1.database_id, 
    --table1.physical_name, 
    --table1.type_desc
FROM sys.master_files AS table1

INNER JOIN sys.databases AS table2 
ON table1.database_id = table2.database_id

WHERE table1.database_id > 4 AND table1.type_desc = 'LOG' 
AND table2.state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND table2.recovery_model_desc = 'FULL';

OPEN dbcursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @db, @fileName;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN

--print @db;

 SET @cmd = 'USE ['+ @db +']; DBCC SHRINKFILE ('''+@fileName+''',512);'
      PRINT 'USE ['+ @db +']; DBCC SHRINKFILE ('''+@fileName+''',512);'
        EXECUTE (@cmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @db, @fileName;
END
CLOSE dbcursor;
DEALLOCATE dbcursor;
END
```

end here the result :

[image]

[image]

The requested value was 512MO but the current value on disk is around 650MO. If I restart the query with

```
USE [BASE2]; DBCC SHRINKFILE ('BASE2_log',8);
USE [BASE3]; DBCC SHRINKFILE ('BASE3_log',8);
```

the value on disk will be around 250 MO. So why my firt query did not shrink the log files to the requested value 512 MO ? Indeed, There was no active VLF at the end of file and still a lot of unused space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037(v=sql.105).aspx) (Section:How Does Shrinking the Log File Work?):

> When any file is shrunk, the space freed must come from the end of the
>   file. When a transaction log file is shrunk, enough virtual log files
>   from the end of the log file are freed to reduce the log to the size
>   requested by the user. **The target_size specified by the user is
>   rounded to the next highest virtual log file boundary**.

You have 1GB and 2GB log files which equate to 8 and 16 vlf's of 131,072.  You said shrink to 512MB (524,288kb).  Since that is on a VLF boundary, it gets rounded up to the next highest VLF boundary (add 131,072) which would be (655,360kb) which is fairly close to the disk space allocation you're seeing.